# Создание одного DataFrame на основе двух разных массивов

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать df на основе двух разных массивов.

На основе одного массива заполнял вот так и все работало корректно

```
df = DataFrame([{
        'open': c.open,
        'close': c.close,
    } for c in mass1])
```

В ответ получал

```
      open   close
801  152.74  152.72
802  152.72  152.76
803  152.76  152.76
804  152.77  152.77
805  152.77  152.76
806  152.77  152.76
807  152.75  152.79
808  152.79  152.76
809  152.76  152.79
810  152.81  152.81
```

Второй массив попытался дописать вот так, но df формируется неправильно

```
df = DataFrame([{
        'open': c.open,
        'close': c.close,
    } for c in mass1], [{
        'open2': c.open,
        'close2': c.close
    } for c in mass2])
```

Вывод, который получаю в консоль:

```
                                      open   close
{'open2': 152.74, 'close2': 152.72}  152.74  152.72
{'open2': 152.72, 'close2': 152.76}  152.72  152.76
{'open2': 152.76, 'close2': 152.76}  152.76  152.76
{'open2': 152.77, 'close2': 152.77}  152.77  152.77
{'open2': 152.77, 'close2': 152.76}  152.77  152.76
{'open2': 152.77, 'close2': 152.76}  152.77  152.76
{'open2': 152.75, 'close2': 152.79}  152.75  152.79
{'open2': 152.79, 'close2': 152.76}  152.79  152.76
{'open2': 152.76, 'close2': 152.79}  152.76  152.79
{'open2': 152.81, 'close2': 152.81}  152.81  152.81
```

Comment: Вы попробуйте читать документации к функциям - много интересного узнаете. второй массив у вас в pd.DataFrame воспринимается как индекс, отсюда и результат. У вас вообще системно неверный подход - вы формируете фрейм из списка  словарей с одиночными значениями.  а нужно - из словаря со значениями в виде списка.

Comment: как-нибудь так: `df = DataFrame({"open":[c.open for c in mass1], "close":[c.close for c in in mass1], "open2": [c.open for c in mass2], "close2:[c.close for c in mass2]}`.

Comment: Если списки точно одинаковой длины, то ещё так можно: `df = DataFrame([{'open1': c1.open, 'close1': c1.close, 'open2': c2.open, 'close2': c2.close} for c1,c2 in zip(mass1, mass2)])`